# What do $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ mean?

Tags: notation

If we see the following:

$\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{Z}^n$, what do they refer to?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ ?

Comment: @Djaian. Yes, exactly

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ means the "n-fold Cartesian product" of the real numbers I.e. the set of all n-tuples $(x_1,...,x_n)$ of real numbers. $\mathbb{Z}^n$ means the same thing for the integers.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $R^n$ refers to the Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $R$, which is an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field of the real numbers.

Same is the case with $Z^n$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is actually not a field :)

Comment: Point noted and changed !